# Trouble with Django unnecessarily adding 5 hours to date time.

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm working a with an app that has a post (sticky note like) object. Here is the post model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(Account)
content = models.CharField(max_length=40)
start_time = models.DateTimeField()

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '{0}'.format(self.content)
```

When I create the post with a certain start time, suppose 3 pm, then I am accordingly getting Fri Feb 20 2015 15:00:00 GMT-0500 in the debugging console. But in the database, it is saved as 20:00:00. And when I display the post to the screen, it is displayed with the database time of 20:00:00.

In settings.py, I have changed:

```
TIME_ZONE = None

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

But the problem persists and I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django stores dates in the db as UTC, so the time `20:00` is correct.  If you want all your dates displayed as the `GMT-0500` timezone you should set the `TIME_ZONE` setting and `USE_TZ = True`... otherwise currently Django doesn't know what time zone you want and it'd be up to you to normalise any dates yourself eg in view code.

Comment: I changed the time to 'America/New_York', I set USE_TZ to true and I still have the same problem. In the database it is stored as 2015-04-04T20:04:00Z and it is displayed as 2015-04-04T20:04:00Z.

Comment: I can only suggest have a look at the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/ ...also double check that your datetime is tz aware https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.is_aware it looks like it is if it displays with `Z` at the end but might be a clue what's wrong if not

Answer (score 2):

It's because the datetime that is stored in the database is *aware* in that along date and time data, it also stores the time zone. When printing the aware datetime object, what you get is that very point in time, but in the UTC time zone (thus the 5hours delta).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from django.utils.timezone import now

>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 15, 29, 10, 202480)

>>> now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 21, 29, 11, 459850, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

As you can see, the `datetime.now()` returns datetime object that is in my local time (-6 hours). The *aware* object is represented in the UTC timezone, which is +6 hours to my local time zone.

If you would like to make it into your local timezone use `django.utils.timezone.localtime`:

```
>>> from django.utils.timezone import now, localtime
>>> localtime(now())
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 15, 31, 25, 666377, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CST-1 day, 18:00:00 STD>)
```

Comment: Amazing! The conversion line "localtime(now())" is just the way to convert one objet into the other